# How to disable mpm-itk for a specific virtualhost?

Tags: apache2, sudo, security, php

I've a main site on a server that needs to run a `sudo` command which I white listed via `visudo`. That worked fine until I installed `apache-mpm-itk` and then I started getting the following error:

```
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, -1): Operation not permitted
```

I would like to disable `mpm-itk` for this specific site, while enabling it for all other sites on the server.  Is there a way to do that via the site config within VirtualHost?  Or if I need 1 site to do a `sudo` command then I'm out of luck with `mpm-itk`?

Comment: Close voters: How is this off-topic?